# most efficient way of generating a plot with 2 different y-axis and points colored by another variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame with 4 columns:

- record_number
- current
- capacity
- step_name: four values a, b, c, d

I'd like to generate a chart using matplotlib:
 [image: required chart]

Chart:

- X-axis: record number
- Y-axis: current and capacity
- markers: colored by the value of step_name

I am trying this code but it generates an error.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 8))
df.plot.scatter('record_number', 'current', c ='step_name' ,ax=ax1)
df.plot.scatter('record_number', 'capacity', c ='step_name', ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Is there a simple way to create a colormap from the unique values of a dataframe column? Do you need to do this using a custom function? Can pandas/matplotlib figure it out like Tableau does?

Here is a sample of some data from the data frame. You can copy the data and use the `pd.read_clipboard()` to generate a data frame. I will try to figure out a different way to provide this information.

```
record_number   current capacity    step_name
16299   13.744  72.042  c
60942   24.33   53.954  c
78204   24.332  9.313   c
37146   24.327  54.379  c
60533   24.331  51.189  c
85517   24.331  58.738  c
48782   -24.325 -51.974 d
84008   24.334  48.54   c
76814   0   0   a
85310   24.329  57.339  c
70417   -24.326 -36.958 d
4822    -24.312 -32.166 b
24782   -24.321 -51.183 d
57664   24.336  31.799  c
43586   -24.33  -16.86  d
61505   24.33   57.759  c
74553   -24.332 -64.909 d
30388   24.329  8.705   c
26213   -24.333 -60.854 d
48086   -24.33  -47.271 d
9344    24.325  25.703  c
51946   -24.33  -73.356 d
40327   11.332  74.809  c
49750   -24.329 -58.516 d
85586   24.331  59.205  c
12217   24.33   45.12   c
58459   24.329  37.172  c
4596    -24.35  -30.639 b
83811   24.327  47.208  c
67173   -24.324 -15.036 d
59496   24.329  44.181  c
71065   -24.329 -41.337 d
9260    24.33   25.135  c
61812   24.327  59.834  c
28831   -5.316  -75.849 d
58634   24.328  38.355  c
13060   24.33   50.818  c
86841   24.328  67.687  c
23905   -24.325 -45.257 d
7888    24.33   15.863  c
61286   24.331  56.279  c
69391   -24.33  -30.025 d
11508   24.326  40.329  c
56630   24.333  24.811  c
31293   24.33   14.821  c
70474   -24.326 -37.343 d
49720   -24.325 -58.313 d
53255   24.33   2.001   c
78431   24.325  10.848  c
49790   -24.32  -58.786 d
21280   -24.323 -27.517 d
70510   -24.331 -37.587 d
56135   24.329  21.465  c
82821   24.329  40.518  c
12037   24.327  43.904  c
60760   24.33   52.724  c
59509   24.328  44.269  c
32294   24.328  21.586  c
22478   -24.324 -35.613 d
38317   24.331  62.293  c
30806   24.331  11.53   c
55349   24.323  16.153  c
21376   -24.326 -28.166 d
17742   -24.327 -3.608  d
39891   21.075  72.892  c
56550   24.325  24.27   c
3110    -24.301 -20.597 b
38899   24.331  66.226  c
4841    -24.354 -32.295 b
47390   -24.329 -42.567 d
23584   -24.335 -43.087 d
10756   24.329  35.246  c
32356   24.328  22.005  c
69773   -24.332 -32.606 d
86246   24.33   63.665  c
29851   24.335  5.075   c
25986   -24.325 -59.32  d
16786   6.566   73.361  c
40008   17.998  73.525  c
50391   -24.326 -62.848 d
28543   -8.234  -75.318 d
36890   24.329  52.649  c
46688   -24.325 -37.823 d
51818   -24.323 -72.491 d
26355   -24.336 -61.813 d
56514   24.329  24.027  c
26702   -24.336 -64.158 d
35480   24.33   43.119  c
13826   24.33   55.995  c
70074   -24.324 -34.64  d
14013   24.329  57.259  c
19769   -24.327 -17.306 d
16964   5.015   73.645  c
76072   -12.77  -74.762 d
65279   -24.331 -2.236  d
6778    24.327  8.361   c
41577   -24.332 -3.283  d
5987    24.326  3.015   c
78560   24.331  11.719  c
11034   24.333  37.125  c
```

Comment: Please, could you add a sample of the dataframe? Will help people testing their solution!

Comment: If you're using matplotlib, you can color based on a column using the `hue` parameter

Comment: `sns.lineplot(data=df,x='record_number', y='current', hue='step_name', ax=ax1)` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `pandas` and `matplotlib` only, this should work:

```
#sorting dataframe along record_number column
df = df.sort_values('record_number')

#creating an index group for each separate set of rows with the same set_name 
df['gg'] = (df['step_name'] != df['step_name'].shift()).cumsum()

#associating a color to the step_name
cols = {'a':'b', 'b':'g', 'c':'r', 'd':'c'}

#plotting
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 8))
for (sn, gidx), sdf in df.groupby(['step_name', 'gg']):
    ax1.plot(sdf['record_number'], sdf['current'], c=cols[sn], label=sn)
    ax2.plot(sdf['record_number'], sdf['capacity'], c=cols[sn], label=sn)

#setting axis labels
plt.xlabel('record_number')
ax1.set_ylabel('current')
ax2.set_ylabel('capacity')

#making the legend, removing repeated entries
handles, labels = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
f_h = []
f_l = []
for h, l in zip(handles, labels):
    if l not in f_l:
        f_h.append(h)
        f_l.append(l)
plt.legend(f_h, f_l)

plt.show()
```

This codes produces, using your sample data:

[image]

`pandas` plotting functions produce nice results, but not very customizable. To make complex plots, in general is better to use `matplotlib` functions.

Here I created an extra row `df['gg']` to mark each group of consecutive rows with the same `'step_name'` with a different index, so that I can groupby over it when plotting (otherwise the result would have been a single line for each color).

Also, you need to associate a color for each letter in your `'step_name'` column (I did it by defining the `col` dictionary). See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/colors_api.html) to know the formats recognized by matplotlib to specify a color.